# Dependency Property does not work after view model was initialized

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I would like to write a custom asynchronous image container custom control. I have created a list from this control:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <custom:CustomImage Width="64" Height="64" BaseUri="{Binding Uri}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The Items property is a list of object A what I initialize in the MainWindowViewModel:

```
public List<A> Items { get; set; } = new List<A>();
```

and

```
foreach (XmlNode item in doc.LastChild.FirstChild.SelectNodes(".//item"))
{
    Items.Add(
        new A
        {
            Title = item.FirstChild.InnerText,
            Uri = new Uri(item.SelectNodes(".//enclosure")[0].Attributes["url"].Value)
        }
    );
}
```

I want to set a Dependency Property on the custom control (you can see above: BaseUri="{Binding Uri}". Uri is a property of the class A.

This is the DP implementation:

```
public Uri BaseUri
{
    get { return (Uri)GetValue(BaseUriProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BaseUriProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BaseUriProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("BaseUri", typeof(Uri),
 typeof(CustomImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Uri), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

It works only if the CustomImage custom control doesn't have any view model. If I do this in the CustomImage's constructor:

```
DataContext = new CustomImageViewModel();
```

it doesn't work anymore.

Any idea?

Comment: Besides what's said in the answer, you should use `ObservableCollection<A>` instead of `List<A>` as type of the `Items` property, to enable built-in change notification when items are added to or removed from the collection.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to make sense that the `BaseUri` property binds two-way by default (or at all).

Comment: Finally "asynchronous image container" seems odd, when you could just use an Image control and set its Source property to a BitmapImage, which already implements asynchronous loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl. Doing so effectively prevents that the DataContext is inherited from the control's parent, as it is required by a binding like

```
BaseUri="{Binding Uri}"
```

So, remove the line

```
DataContext = new CustomImageViewModel();
```

from the constructor of your control.

---

It is not true that the "control doesn't have any view model" when you don't set it explicitly. In fact, the view model (or the inherited DataContext) is set - via the ItemsControl's item container - to the appropriate item from the `ItemsSource` collection. So the `DataContext` of your control is automatically set to an instance of your class `A`.

Comment: But I want a separate view model for the custom control which contains all async operation (and other bindable properties) I need. Is it possible?

Comment: "Is it possible?" Yes, but it doesn't make sense. You want to bind your control's properties like `BaseUri="{Binding Uri}"`, so a DataContext must be inherited.

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks!